# How can I make a method act as a tap on a MKAnnotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, annotations, mapkit

I have two views. One is a map view and another is a table view of all of the titles of the `MKAnnotation`s. Right now I am able to call a method on the table view from the tap of the `MKAnnotation`. **But what I want to also do is call a method from the tap of an object on the table view that acts as a tap on the `MKAnnotation`.** Help please?

Here is the table view code that the `MKAnnotation` tap uses to select an object on the table view.

```
- (void)highlightCellForPost:(PAWPost *)post {
// Find the cell matching this object.
NSUInteger index = 0;
for (PFObject *object in [self objects]) {
    PAWPost *postFromObject = [[PAWPost alloc] initWithPFObject:object];
    if ([post isEqual:postFromObject]) {
        // We found the object, scroll to the cell position where this object is.
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:PAWWallPostsTableViewMainSection];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

        return;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Here's is the code for the `MKAnnotation` that calls the above method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
id<MKAnnotation> annotation = [view annotation];
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PAWPost class]]) {
    PAWPost *post = [view annotation];
    [self.wallPostsTableViewController highlightCellForPost:post];
} else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    // Center the map on the user's current location:
    CLLocationAccuracy filterDistance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:PAWUserDefaultsFilterDistanceKey];
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.currentLocation.coordinate,
                                                                      filterDistance * 2.0f,
                                                                      filterDistance * 2.0f);

    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
    self.mapPannedSinceLocationUpdate = NO;
}
```

}

**So I essentially want to do what I've done above but in reverse order.**

Comment: Just call `[mapView selectAnnotation:post]` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I can't call mapView from my tableView because they are in different mapview is in a viewController that tableView is a sub view of. Any way to get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call `selectAnnotation` on your map view in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Firstly, I would create a new NSArray property `postObjects` which contains all of the PFObjects in `self.objects` already converted to `PAWPost` objects rather than having to continually iterate the objects array and create new PAWPost objects. Once you do this, your first method becomes the much simpler -

```
- (void)highlightCellForPost:(PAWPost *)post {
// Find the cell matching this object.
    NSUInteger index = [self.posts indexOfObject:post];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:PAWWallPostsTableViewMainSection];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

Then, your tableview method is

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == PAWWallPostsTableViewMainSection) {
        PAWPost *post=self.posts[indexPath.row];
        [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:post.coordinate animated:YES];
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:post animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention that mapView is in a viewController that my tableView is a sub view of. So I cannot access mapView from table view. How would I fix that problem?

Comment: Firstly I would think about having a single view controller, but otherwise you need to set a property in your table view controller that holds a reference to your mapView - just as you have done in your mal view controller for your tableView